# Query to join 2 tables and keep only 1 row from one of the tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables (item and item_historic) and i'm looking for a query that keep the last item_historic line (max date) and join it to the item table.

**item :**

```
id_item     state_item
5560        complete
5570        removed
```

**item_historic :**

```
id_historic id_item     state_historic  date
2002        5560        declared        2011-01-13 13:32:15
2198        5560        complete        2011-03-14 11:44:40
1780        5570        declared        2011-03-15 15:26:55
2208        5570        removed         2011-04-15 08:17:59
```

**result :**

```
id_item id_historic state_item      date                state_historic
5560    2198        complete        2011-03-14 11:44:40 complete
5570    2208        removed         2011-04-15 08:17:59 removed
```

I want one id_item only.

I hope that make sense and thanks in advance.

EDIT : wrong result and my question is what should the query look like ?
Tried :

```
select ah.id_item, ah.id_historic, at.state, date, ah.id_type, ah.state_item  from item at left join item_historic ah on ah.id_item = at.id_item group by ah.id_item order by max(date) ;
```

Comment: how you get `state_historic` in result?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the `not exists` approach is often the most efficient:

```
select ah.id_attestation, ah.id_historic, at.state, date, ah.id_type, ah.state_aft 
from `via-energica_plateforme`.attestation at left join
     `via-energica_plateforme`.attestation_historic ah
     on ah.id_attestation = at.id_attestation
where not exists (select 1
                  from `via-energica_plateforme`.attestation_historic ah2
                  where ah2.id_item = ah.id_item and
                        ah2.date > ah.date
                 );
```

This query will work best with an index on `attestation_historic(id_item, date)`.

The `not exists` clause takes some getting used to in this context.  It is saying "choose the row from `ah` where there is no more recent row from the table" -- which is that same as "get the maximum date".  The advantage in MySQL is that no aggregation is required, and aggregation can be an expensive operation.  But, for performance, you really need to compare the two approaches.

Comment: Interesting approach. I would not have thought to use "not exists" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a way of doing it with a sub-query:

```
SELECT i.id_item, ih.id_historic, i.state_item, sq.max_date as `date`, ih.state_historic
FROM attestation i
    INNER JOIN (SELECT id_item, MAX(`date`) AS max_date FROM attestation_historic GROUP BY id_item) AS sq ON i.id_item = sq.id_item
    INNER JOIN attestation_historic ih ON i.id_item = ih.id_item AND sq.max_date = ih.`date`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's another way, but this would work:

```
SELECT t.id_item, t.id_historic, i.state_item, t.date, t.state_historic FROM item i 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * 
FROM id_historic ORDER BY DATE DESC) t GROUP BY t.`id_item`
) t ON t.id_item = i.id_item ORDER BY t.date;
```